# How should i do to reference one file in my project, so when i publish the application, the file is generated in a specific folder?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, deployment

the problem that i have with my application is about how to reference some files, when i load and image, etc, i use `Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "..\\..\\..\\"));` and this works fine for debugging and for some files, but doesn't work for some essential files, credentials.txt, config.ini, this files are searched in appdata when i run the published file and i don't know how i should reference them.

I try to generate some initial files so i am sure where they are and that they exists, but for folders that works great with

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

with that i can make the folders where the app is run but you can't generate a file without load the content of the original file, and i don't know how to reference them.

Example:

**Project.**

Root of the project.

utils/key/credentials.txt

- When the published file is executed i want to generate and store credentials.txt like this:

**Executable** (app.exe stored for example in "my documents")

"my documents"/utils/key/credentials.txt

how i do that? when i run the published application you just have the .exe, the dlls, and the resources are embebbed, so the uri doesn't works.

Comment: Is "my documents" an existing folder? Or do you want to create it at runtime?

Comment: an existing folder i mean the folder for documents in windows

Comment: That's what just an example, what i wanted was to generate the initial files in the output directory where the executable is, example if i publish app.exe and app.exe is in desktop, i run app.exe and this made util folder, then in desktop/util/ generate credentials.txt

Comment: See my answer then.

Comment: yes i marked it as the answer, i was searching exactly that, now i can reference the file because i know where is going to be in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have sufficient permissions, you could create a folder in the output folder of your compiled `.exe` at runtime using the [Directory.CreateDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-create-a-file-or-folder?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) method.

If the `utils/key/credentials.txt` file is part of your deployment, you should set its **Build Action** to **Content** and the **Copy to Output Directory property** to **Copy if newer** in Visual Studio. This will add the `utils` and `key` folders to the output directory of the `.exe`, which is typically c:<project-folder\bin\Debug or \Release when you build from Visual Studio.

You can get the absolute path of the output directory like this:

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
```

Depending on your requirements, you may then append the relative path of the file within your app to the absolute path.